# Max value of column and their state if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table (tbl_payments) with 4 columns like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------------+  
| User_id    | Name       | Status|  Due_dates |
+------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Now imagine records like this.

```
1| Luigi | Active | 0
1| Luigi | Active | 0
1| Luigi | Active | 30
2| Peach | Active | 0
2| Peach | Active | 30
2| Peach | Active | 60
2| Peach | Active | 90
2| Peach | OFF    | 0
3| Bowser| Active | 0
3| Bowser| Active | 30
3| Bowser| PAID   | 0
```

I need a query that returns the PAID and OFF users, with their max due date, excluding Active users.

The output would be something like this.

```
2| Peach | OFF   | 90
3| Bowser| PAID  | 30
```

I have tried some subqueries without success, any clue would help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: We need to see your query.  Also, please explain how the query isn't giving you the results you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max(due_dates)over(partition by user_id)` window function to get the max due_dates for each user. Then select users with only OFF and Paid status from the results.

```
 CREATE TABLE USERS ( User_id INT, Name varchar(10),Status varchar(10),  Due_dates int);
 
 insert into USERS values(1, 'Luigi','Active' , 0);
 insert into USERS values(1, 'Luigi','Active' , 0);
 insert into USERS values(1, 'Luigi','Active' , 30);
 insert into USERS values(2, 'Peach','Active' , 0);
 insert into USERS values(2, 'Peach','Active' , 30);
 insert into USERS values(2, 'Peach','Active' , 60);
 insert into USERS values(2, 'Peach','Active' , 90);
 insert into USERS values(2, 'Peach', 'OFF'   , 0);
 insert into USERS values(3, 'Bowser', 'Active' , 0);
 insert into USERS values(3, 'Bowser', 'Active' , 30);
 insert into USERS values(3, 'Bowser', 'PAID'   , 0);
```

Query:

```
 select * from 
 (
   select user_id,name,status,max(due_dates)over(partition by user_id) max_Due_dates 
   from USERS 
 )t
 where status in ('OFF','PAID')
 GO
```

Output:

| user_id | name | status | max_Due_dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Peach | OFF | 90 |
| 3 | Bowser | PAID | 30 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=307de794344340e1c02c179b0b3d82bc)*

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want aggregation with filtering *after* the aggregation:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when status <> 'Active' then status end), max(due_date)
from t
group by id, name
having sum(case when status <> 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not test the below code but that should solve it or get you close.

> SELECT user_id, name, status, Max(due_date) from tbl_payments group by status
> having status = "OFF" and status = "PAID"